# Carousel replacing images on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

Ive done some googling but i didnt find nothing suitable for my problem.
Is somewhere out there slider/carousel which has visible i.e 4 images every moment and after hover on one of the exact one image is swapped with another one ?
Also if not is there a way to modify some well known sliders such as `flexslider` to work that way ? 
So far i tried modify flexsliders code like this

CSS

```
#cf {
  position:relative;

  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="flexslider" >
  <ul class="slides" >
    <li>
      <div id="cf">
        <img class="bottom" src="img/artists/arendarik_p.jpg" />
        <img class="top" src="img/artists/arendarik.jpg" />
      </div>
    </li>
    ...
```

but after adding more images i had to set them exact laft margin according to width of image which somehow broke flexslider

thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and create a jquery script to change image on mouse hover like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#carousel-div").hover(
owl.trigger('owl.next');


)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it this way using flexslider and simple javascript

```
<div class="flexslider" >
        <ul class="slides" >
            <li>
              <a href="subArtists/arendarik.html">
              <img src="img/artists/arendarik.jpg" 
                 onmouseover="this.src='img/artists/arendarik_p.jpg'"
                 onmouseout="this.src='img/artists/arendarik.jpg'"
                  border="0" alt=""/></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                 .
                 .
                 .
            </ul>
       </div
```